# Some times my bot can't flow continue. one card continues looping.(directline specific problem and not rise in MS-Teams)

Tags: javascript, node.js, botframework, microsoft-teams, direct-line-botframework

Some time flow can't continue. if I reload then working fine. 
this kind of problem arises for some users in Directline.
the problem not phased in MS-Teams any user.

when I sent a message with hero card buttons and that hero card continues looping. it does not raise problems all the time. only rise some users only Directline specific.

I used bot framework v4 in NodeJS. any idea about why this kind of problem arises?

in bot flow, I have 2 hero cards,
one card I sent then I write this **return Dialog.EndOfTurn;**
so user input I got. in the next set I sent the second card. 
but the second step does not get the flow sometimes. for diretcline some random users.

Here code:

```
let choiceButtons = [];
questionObject.answers.forEach(answerItem => {
    choiceButtons.push({
        type: ActionTypes.ImBack,
        title: answerItem.answer,
        value: answerItem.answer
    });
});

// construct hero card.
const card = CardFactory.heroCard('', undefined, choiceButtons, {text: ''});

let reply = {type: ActivityTypes.Message};
// add card to Activity.
reply.attachments = [card];
reply.text = questionObject.question.toString();

await step.context.sendActivity(reply);
return Dialog.EndOfTurn;
```

Comment: What type of card actions are your cards using? Can you provide the code that creates the cards?

Comment: @KyleDelaney above I edit the code.

Comment: So I'm guessing that code is in a waterfall step. When you say the hero card continues looping I presume you mean the step gets repeated and the hero card gets resubmitted to the conversation each time the user clicks a button. And you're saying the issue is intermittent, meaning it doesn't always happen in Direct Line all the time for every user. Is all that correct?

Comment: Are you still working on this?

Comment: Yaa, but sometimes only happen in this situation. maybe bot-framework DirectLine problem because I tested in other channels many times and many other users. but this kind of looping situation they not raised.  only directline channel found this problem. if any bug in coding then all channel rises this kind of problem but its rises in directline only. also, I see the logs from UI side proper sending the text but in the backend dialog not continue sometime and looping. @KyleDelaney

Comment: Are you using Web Chat or your own Direct Line client?

Comment: Do you still need help?

Comment: @KyleDelaney Just I need why this kind of problem arises.

Comment: There's no way for anyone to know why the problem arises based only on the information you've given, so if you want help you will need to provide more. Answering my questions is good, and being forthcoming with information is better. If the problem is channel-related then it probably has to do with the behavior of card actions, but I would need to know whether you're using Web Chat or your own Direct Line client. Perhaps there's a difference between the activities that an `imBack` sends to your bot in Teams vs. your Direct Line client, and then your bot responds differently to them.

Comment: Thanks, your point noted but now I converted my bot framework version 4.5

Comment: Are you saying you no longer encounter the problem?

Comment: As of now the problem no rises, I changed the bot framework 4.5 Coding structure. i'm getting the issue again then a will tell you. Thanks

Comment: Would you like to post that as an answer so you can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was resolved by updating Microsoft Bot Framework all packages update with 4.7,
packages look like:

```
    "botbuilder": "4.7.2",
    "botbuilder-ai": "4.7.2",
    "botbuilder-azure": "4.7.2",
    "botbuilder-dialogs": "4.7.2",
    "botframework-config": "4.7.2",
    "botframework-connector": "4.7.2",
```